# milesj cakephp AutoLogin Component - _autoLogin function

Tags: cakephp, autologin

I have been sucessfully using the [AutoLogin component](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/auto-login) for a while now and it's great however for some reason I cannot seem to get the _autoLogin function option to work, I need to update the users last_login field when the cookie logs them in.

Has anyone been able to get this to work correctly? No matter what I put it in nothing happens so I assume it is being ignored or not found.

My code is something like this below, I have tried putting it in the AppController, the UserController and the User model, nothing seems to happen.

```
public function _autoLogin($user) 
{
    debug($user);
    $this->User->id = $user['User']['id']; // target correct record
    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM)); // save login time
}
```

Thannks

Comment: did you debug $user - what comes in?

Comment: Yes I did try that, the developer of the plugin updated me yesterday saying it has to go into the UsersController file, my updated code is above to reflect this, still the debug($user) doesn't produce anything. Thanks

Comment: you need to `die()`; afterwards. what would you expect if directly afterwards the redirect jumps in and clears it through a page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up having to go into the AppController.php file.

My new code is as follows:

```
public function _autoLogin($user) 
{
    //echo $user);
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->id = $user; // target correct record
    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM)); // save login time
}
```

This works.